# delay in adding circles in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

i have a line(x-y axis) and some data points on that line. line is moving from right to left based on some fixed interval of 200ms and the data points on the line are also moving along with the line.
But the issue is that, there is some delay in the movement of circles. See the jsfiddle(scroll to the right on fiddle page to see the issue i.e. delay in circle movement)

https://jsfiddle.net/rajatmehta/tm5166e1/13/

```
chartBody.selectAll(".dot1")
  .data(globalData, function(d){ return d.timestamp; })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot1")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.timestamp);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

    chartBody.selectAll(".dot2")
  .data(globalDataNew, function(d){ return d.timestamp; })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot2")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.timestamp);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

  d3.selectAll(".dot1")
    //.data(globalData)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(dx) + ")");


  d3.selectAll(".dot2")
    //.data(globalDataNew)
    .transition()
    .ease("linear")
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(dxNew) + ")");
```

how to prevent this delay ?

Answer (score 1):

You can select dot1 and dot2 at same time and apply transition. 
Currently you are selecting them and apply transition to each of them separately hence the delay

Comment: i tried that too, still getting the delay.

please find the code and correct me if i m doing something wrong : 

https://jsfiddle.net/rajatmehta/tm5166e1/15/

Comment: @RajatMehta
I am having look at your code, have you noticed the motion is somewhat smooth than earlier. Probably there must something which is making it slow...having a look at that.

Comment: ya but i see a lot of delay in the transition of the circles. not getting the solution :/

Comment: @RajatMehta
you can have a look at this jsfillde https://jsfiddle.net/ajinkyadhote/x2qtesh4/

i have updated your code so that it will update path1, path2 and cicrcle simultaneously

    
   `d3.selectAll("path#path1, path#path2, circle")
     .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(dx) + ")");`

Comment: i cannot see any change in the code, its the same code that i provided. I think its not updated. can you please check once?

Comment: @RajatMehta can you see it now, i have updated the code. 
just go to end of code.

Comment: still its the same:

these are the last lines of ur code   

    chartBody.selectAll(".dot2")
  .data(globalDataNew, function(d){ return d.timestamp; })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot2")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.timestamp);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

  d3.selectAll("circle")
    //.data(globalData)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(dx) + ")");

 svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}

Comment: can you please post the complete code snippet here ?

Comment: `d3.selectAll("path#path1, path#path2, circle")
     .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(dx) + ")");
    `